# How to add accents etc to letters using the "English (UK)" input source?

Tags: input-method

How can I use the "English (UK)" input source on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 to add accents etc to letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the UK keyboard layout chart:

[image: UK keyboard layout chart]

you'll see a ton of tertiary and quaternary symbols per key.

These are used with the <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> for the tertiary and <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> for the quaternary ones, so <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> will give you <kbd>°</kbd>, so you can now write: -40°C = -40°F

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Fabby's answer, don't forget about the Compose key <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

The keys must be pressed in that order, as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> gives the dead-key, as described by Fabby.

For example, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd> gives you `°`. (Note that you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then <kbd>AltGr</kbd> at the same time, then let go of both keys before pressing <kbd>o</kbd>, and <kbd>o</kbd> again.)

More examples that can be obtained with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>:

- é: <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd>
- ç: <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd>
- ö: <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>
- ß: <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>
- ½: <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>
- →: <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>></kbd>
- — (em-dash): <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>

Refer to `/usr/share/X11/locale/${LANG}/Compose` for a full list. (If the file doesn't exist, use your closest `${LANG}`. For example, my `${LANG}` is `en_GB.UTF-8`, but the nearest file for me is `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`.)

Answer (score 0):

Some suddenly misconfiguration maked me write spanish tildes like "´a". You didn't tell your keyboard layout.

My .xinputrc was old. I solved only excecuting:

```
im-config
```

And I followed choosing 'default'.

If your layout is not in your target accents-language you can write some symbols and all characters with an easy app `gucharmap` (I have it in Xubuntu, maybe in ubuntu works as well)

[image: gucharmap]